# Entity Framework 6 support Filetables

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Does anyone know if Entity Framework 6 supports FileTables yet? I have searched and Googled to no avail. Everything came back about filestreams instead.

Cheers

bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `FILETABLE` is just a "normal" table (albeit with a fixed schema that you cannot define/adapt yourself) - yes, of course you can query against a `FILETABLE` or even insert or delete rows from EF6.

Or what "support" exactly are you looking for?

If you want to really make best use of a `FILETABLE`, and if you want to access the file contents stored in that table, for that operation you'll need to use the `SqlFileStream` class which requires you to use "raw" ADO.NET.

But there's nothing stopping you from just reading out all the columns from a `FILETABLE` in a normal EF fashion - including the stored bytes of the file, if you need to.

Comment: what about the hierachyid, which EF doesn't support?